# Drag&Drop + Overlap in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, drag-and-drop, actor, overlap

First of all, excuse me for my English, I have it a little rusty.
I have a problem with LibGDX. I am making, so to speak, a card game, and I need the cards to have the following effects:

- An action is done when you only click on it.
- Another action is done when the card is dragged.

Both things I have managed to work, the problem comes when, after releasing the card, I must call a function and later return the card to its original position.
The following code is the one that I associate with each Actor, but in the Override methods I don't find any for the DROP.

Can you help me?

Thank you very much in advance!

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PLKo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickListener has a "touchUp" method, which is called when the mouse button (or finger touch) goes up. This is what you want to use when releasing the card. More info here:

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.html#touchUp-com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent-float-float-int-int-

Comment: I already tried with the touchUp and I thought that it did not work since I assigned a "System.out.println" which was not always displayed on the console (I still don't know why). I just retested it by assigning it a function and it works perfectly.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't always work with println. I believe the touchUp method is not called if you press on the actor and then move the mouse (or finger) off of the actor when you release. But since you are moving the actor while dragging, it seems like touchUp should always be called.